# PHP - parse current URL

Tags: php, parsing

I need to parse the current url so that, in either of these cases:

```
http://mydomain.com/abc/
http://www.mydomain.com/abc/
```

I can get the return value of "abc" (or whatever text is in that position). How can I do that?

Comment: Check out the built-in PHP function [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). That should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [parse_url();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/abc/';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

which would give you

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.mydomain.com
    [path] => /abc/
)
/abc/
```

**Update:** to get current page url and then parse it:

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

print_r(parse_url(curPageURL()));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

[source for curPageURL function](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php)

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to get the current url automatically from the browser? I can't hard-code it.

Comment: I have a question, what if you don't use http:// in the url what if i have just mydomain.com/abc/, i tried but it returns only path.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević I had to remove the PHP_URL_PATH, and use the default argument (-1) so that it would return an array like in the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at the [`parse_url()`](http://ca.php.net/parse_url) function. It'll break you URL into its component parts. The part you're concerned with is the path, so you can pass `PHP_URL_PATH` as the second argument. If you only want the first section of the path, you can then use `explode()` to break it up using `/` as a delimiter.

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/abc/";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathComponents = explode("/", trim($path, "/")); // trim to prevent
                                                  // empty array elements
echo $pathComponents[0]; // prints 'abc'
```

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve the current URL, you can use something like `$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

If you want to match *exactly* what is between the first and the second / of the path, try using directly `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
<?php

function match_uri($str)
{
  preg_match('|^/([^/]+)|', $str, $matches);

  if (!isset($matches[1]))
    return false;

  return $matches[1];  
}

echo match_uri($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Just for fun, a version with `strpos()` + `substr()` instead of `preg_match()` which should be a few microseconds faster:

```
function match_uri($str)
{
  if ($str{0} != '/')
    return false;

  $second_slash_pos = strpos($str, '/', 1);

  if ($second_slash_pos !== false)
    return substr($str, 1, $second_slash_pos-1);
  else
    return substr($str, 1);
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/abc/"; //https://www... http://... https://...
echo substr(parse_url($url)['path'],1,-1); //return abc
?>
```

Comment: Note: `echo parse_url($url)['path'];`  returns `/abc/`  Then `substr(...,1,-1)` removes the leading and trailing slashes `/`, so the final result becomes `abc`

Comment: You could also use the optional argument for trim(). `trim(parse_url($url)['path'],'/')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.in/abc/';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_host);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?function urlSegment($i = NULL) {
static $uri;
if ( NULL === $uri )
{
    $uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );
    $uri = explode( '/', $uri );
    $uri = array_filter( $uri );
    $uri = array_values( $uri );
}
if ( NULL === $i )
{
    return '/' . implode( '/', $uri );
}
$i =  ( int ) $i - 1;
$uri = str_replace('%20', ' ', $uri);
return isset( $uri[$i] ) ? $uri[$i] : NULL;} ?>
```

sample address in browser: http://localhost/this/is/a/sample url

```
<?  urlSegment(1); //this
urlSegment(4); //sample url?>
```