# What is req.params(expressJS) in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, express

In PHP,
we have $GET which translates to req.query in nodeJS
and we have $POST which translates to req.body in nodeJS

so how do you get req.params in PHP?

For example my request URL is http://cat.api/cat/steven

In Nodejs if we use route /cat/:name we can get `req.params.name` //steven
How do we get the same data using PHP?

Comment: You need php router, for example Klein - https://github.com/klein/klein.php

Answer (score -1):

See
[PHP - parse current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598480/php-parse-current-url)

See the documentation here: http://php.net/parse_str