# unlimited parameters get last one

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm using codeigniter. How can I get last part of my URL like:

> www.example.com/uk-en/category/subcategory

Parameters may be unlimited or there may be only one. Inside of my Controller Home and method Index, I just want last part of url e.g "subcategory"

1. if url is www.example.com/uk-en/category I want "category"
2. if url is www.example.com/uk-en I want "uk-en"

---

### Edit

if url is www.example.com/Home/index/uk-en/category then it's working
but What i want without class name "Home" and method "index"

### Like this  www.example.com/uk-en/category

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function index($params=[]){
      $params=func_get_args();
     $last=end($params);
     echo $last;
    }
}
?>
```

`routes.php`

```
   <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    $route['(:any)'] = 'Home/index';
    $route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
    $route['404_override'] = 'error_404/index';
    $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
    ?>
```

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: If nothing else, you could use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - parse current URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598480/php-parse-current-url)

Comment: Regis Portalez using parse current URL how can i access class home and method index .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your routs

```
$route['(.*)'] = "Home/index";
```

This to print all routs in your controller in your index function

```
print_r($this->uri->segment_array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your routes is with setting wildcard placeholder on first place. It always need to be at last place.

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = 'error_404/index';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

//some example routes
$route['specific/route'] = 'controller/method';
$route['specific/(:num)'] = 'page/show/$1';

//always put your wildcard route at the end of routes.php file
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index';
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards).