# Code Igniter: default controller for unrouted requests

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CI setup where a URL may invoke a specific controller OR should be forwarded to a catch-all controller where no such controller exists. Sort of like `default` in a switch statement. Examples:

```
domain/real-controller          //<-- handled by controllers/Real-controller.php
domain/another-real-controller  //<-- controllers/Another-real-controller.php
domain/foobar                   //<-- no such controller; forwarded to a catch-all
```

I'm aware of rerouting, but I can't do

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'catchall_controller'
```

as this will (presumably) block reqeusts to legitimate controllers.

I could presumably do something hacky with 404 handling, but I wondered if there was a better way. **Anyone know one?**

Comment: why not -`$route['default_controller'] = catchall_controller';` ?

Comment: That's being used, to ensure that going to `www.domain` loads the homepage. I suppose I could set a catch-all default controller that, if no argument is passed, loads the homepage. Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: What version of Codeigniter are you using?

Comment: so if you have this "catch all" controller, would you still need a 404 page? if its catching all requests, then wouldn't 404 be obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

Since this controller is a "catch all", then it is pretty much doing what a 404 page would do. In that case, you can do this in your routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = 'catchall_controller';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Would that still send a 404 header, though? I got round the issue by having a "gatekeeper" default controller that bounce to the homepage *unless* a token was passed. +1, though.

Comment: it will not send a 404 header unless you specify it.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use `$route['(:any)'] = 'catchall_controller'` but you MUST put it on the end of your routes.php file :).

Therefore, every other router/controller can be fulfilled before going to the last line that has your catchall_controller.

Comment: I think this might not be what hes looking for. The point is not to create an entire list of routes, just one "default" or "catch all" route.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I agree with the commenter, though.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter 2 the `(:any)` works for all parameters, but in codeigniter 3 this is changed. Change your route to:

```
$route['(.*)'] = 'catchall_controller';
```

Comment: why would this work? provide an explanation. How does this differ from `$route['(:any)']` ?

Comment: in codeigniter 2 the (:any) work for all parameters but in codeigniter 3 this is change  

see in this to pass perimeters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111876/unlimited-parameters-get-last-one/37113315#37113315

Comment: Thank you for your help.