# Extreme .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have link like this:
http://www.my-website.com/a/something,1234,1,something-else
And i want to redirect it using 301 redirect to url like this:
http://www.my-website.com/other/something-else,1234

And i want to save number "1234" and the part with "something-else" from old url and put it to new url.

It is possible to make?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. htaccess can do this easily for you

Comment: How can I do it. I want to save the number "1234" and the part "somethin-else" and put it to new link.

Comment: [Parse the URL then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598480/php-parse-current-url)