# Match specific urls but not including a php file

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following sample urls

`/alfa/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
/beta/wp-content/plugins/app/js/media.js?parameter=value
/beta/wp-admin/network
/beta/wp-content/themes/journal/data.php`

I'm using the following regex to match all paths, excluding paramethers

```
^/(alfa|beta)((/wp-(content|admin|includes))([^?\s]*)).*
```

This works well, but how to change the regex to exclude any paths which include a .php ? So it needs to return first 3 paths but not the last.

Comment: @Wiktor do you have a good duplicate for this one?

Comment: @mickmackusa Perhap, [PHP - parse current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598480/php-parse-current-url), but I vote as too broad.

Comment: Yeah.  Too many different, correct ways to solve this one.  @JoeS please show more effort and let us know how you go.

Comment: @Wiktor I'am not sure why you tagged this as php, as i'am using it along Nginx rewrite, so obliviously your link is useless.

Comment: @JoeS I've moved my comment to an answer. Please accept if that explains it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PCRE verbs `skip` and `fail` to skip over matches of expressions. You can read more about them here, http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail. For your current example you can use:

```
.*\.php$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^/(alfa|beta)((/wp-(content|admin|includes))([^?\s]*)).*
```

which would skip files that end in `.php`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YH3n0x/1/

The `.*\.php$` looks for anything until a `.php` at the end of the string/line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i looked for is the following, thanks @chris85

```
.*\.php(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^/(alfa|beta)((/wp-(content|admin|includes))([^?\s]*)).*
```