# Get Text after domain name from URL without sending to not found page

Tags: php

I have a domain name say for example : www.example.com
I would like to get a dynamic data using PHP that is after this domain name. Example : www.example.com/**samsung**.

This samsung shall be anything that a user comes from.
I want to get this **samsung** in my PHP. The major problem here is that when ever I open this www.example.com/samsung or www.example.com/vivo page the browser goes to vivo directory and throws a 404 error.

For now I have solved getting the data from this format : www.example.com/?samsung

```
<?php 
$key = array_search('', $_GET);
echo $key;
?>
```

But I want to get rid of the `?` and have a pure *www.example.com/samsung* type.

Comment: Do you use apache or nginx?

Comment: Getting rid of question mark in browser url.! you need to change your php links give like ?samsung in php, if you want to get rid of it where you get last part, then see answer.

Comment: I have figured the fetching data from url. But the real problem is the redirect to 404. Since there is no such folder or file available.

Comment: I use Apache2 by the way

Comment: @YaseenHussain see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you last part of url

```
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$url_array = explode('/',$url);
$result = end($url_array);
$Cleaned_url = str_replace("?", "", $result);
echo $Cleaned_url;
```

**UPDATE :** Creating Seo url :

`.htaccess` File

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ your_page.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

In php file when linking to url.

I save urls in database in news_url column

```
<a href="<?php echo $row["news_url"]; ?>" title="">post title</a>
```

This setup will give you `www.example.com/samsung` and solve your 404 notfound problem with right setup.
**Attetion :** Creating seo urls with htaccess requires knowledge just copy paste wont work.

you can search on google : for how to create seo url with htaccess

This examples are working 100%.

Comment: Or just $result = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

Comment: How to prevent the 404 error redirection at first place.

Comment: @YaseenHussain Ask another question for 404 with details will answer, Sorry, dont know what you are talking about

Comment: When you open example.com/samsung, it takes to a 404 error page because there is no file called samsung or vivo. I want the system to treat samsung as a variable rather than a page. (Just like how codeigniter considers a first variable as controller).

Comment: @YaseenHussain question and your example in question is about this : **Get Text after domain name from URL**. But anyway I gave that answer is well in my comment under your question. its about your php codes and htaccess file there is nothing I can do with that. Search for htaccess seo url with php on google

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598480/php-parse-current-url#5598515)