# Url rewriting using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

[image]

I have a URL that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/DU/edit-product.php?id=1
```

How would I go about converting that URL to:

```
http://localhost/DU/edit/1
```

How to create .htaccess file for this..

Comment: Tell us first what you tried and the issue with it

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695148/12232340 and search on google for **how to create seo urls**

Comment: Put this in your htaccess : `RewriteRule ^DU/edit/(.*)$ edit-product.php?id=$1 [L,NC]` and in php `<a href="DU/edit/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="">edit post</a>`

Comment: not working in my code

Comment: I have the impression the OP did not understand what URL rewriting actually is. The OP expects that the references sent out as part of the php generated content are altered, which is not what URL rewriting does...

Comment: @Krish Instead of complaining you should provide constructive information. Comments like "still not changed", "not working in my code", "I got answer for this" do not help at all. You need to provide actual information fro your side.

Comment: You probably get downvotes because this question shows no effort from your side to solve your problem. Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry guys i am not good in english thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^edit-([0-9]+)$ edit-product.php?id=$1
```

Comment: This rule won't rewrite the URL you posted in your question.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/htaccess-for-all/ kindly verify this

Comment: `edit-1` and `edit/1` are two separate things ...

Comment: Anyway, fine to see that you solved your issue. Have a great day.