# Get part of string PHP

Tags: php, regex

How to get a part of string using PHP?

I have a string like this.

```
https://test-app.com/admin/api/2019-10/orders.json?limit=2&page_info=eyJpZHMiOiIyMDY3MTczMTEzOTg3LDIwNjU0ODU0MzA5MTUsMjA2NTQ3OTI3MDUzMSwyMDYyODE3MzI5MjgzIiwibGFzdF9pZCI6MjA2NTQ4NTQzMDkxNSwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMTcgMTg6MTc6NTkiLCJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0In0
```

I want only the link.. like this

```
orders.json?limit=2&page_info=eyJpZHMiOiIyMDY3MTczMTEzOTg3LDIwNjU0ODU0MzA5MTUsMjA2NTQ3OTI3MDUzMSwyMDYyODE3MzI5MjgzIiwibGFzdF9pZCI6MjA2NTQ4NTQzMDkxNSwibGFzdF92YWx1ZSI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMTcgMTg6MTc6NTkiLCJkaXJlY3Rpb24iOiJuZXh0In0
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

Comment: https://3v4l.org/1rsCC  AND https://3v4l.org/HHhRn

Comment: See this is well https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695148/12232340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not just a string it's a URL so use URL and path functions:

```
$parts = parse_url($str);
echo basename($parts['path']).$parts['query'];
```